# How to compress a standalone exe project under 1MB in size?

Tags: .net, deployment, exe

I have to develop an application that offers some basic functionality as shown in figure:

[image]

It has to display a table of entries that is totally static and does not involve CRUD. I first made this app using .NET winforms but the size of setup (including .net client runtime) reached over 50 MB but my client wants something less than one MB. Is there a way I can develop such application that can run as stand alone executable providing tabular listing of entries, searching and printing. I don't know what language I should target.

Comment: did you check the sample code that comes with dot NET? all of those are compiled into small .exes as I recall. (oh, never mind, he's counting the *runtime*? geesh)

Comment: What's the size minus the .NET client runtime? If you can target .NET 3 then you should be able to ignore the client runtime as it's already installed on all Vista and Windows 7 machines (actually .NET 3.5).

Comment: How much static data do you have (in MB)? Given the requirement, you could possibly try to compress it or make it... dynamic, storing it somewhere on internet and accessing it through a web service?

Comment: Sure your client is not happy with a simple Excel or HTML or PDF sheet?

Comment: @ChrisF its about 10MB including access db file

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that when using C and the native Windows API, it would be possible to create an application without any additional runtime environment to install, which will remain below 1MB. On the other hand: is your client really willing to pay the additional development costs for this approach?

Comment: i have no experience of coding in c/c++. is there any visual designer available that can enable me to quickly develop some GUI features.

Comment: @Muhammad: you would have to learn MFC programming for that (yes, Visual Studio has a GUI designer for that). But as I said: can't you convince your client that this 1MB limit is nonsense by showing him the cost difference: at least 1 month additional development costs since you have to learn MFC first?

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee that this will get you below 1MB, but I'm guessing it'll get you at least close.  You can edit your project properties and set all of the .NET framework items (including the client runtime) as prerequisites to your project. That way they must be installed on the client PC in order for your installation to run and won't be bundled in your installer.

Comment: Unfortunately boss has something similar that is less than 1 MB and he would listen to anything like installing .net framework or windows installer. application is shown in figure. if u can put some light how that could have been developed, i will be thankful

Comment: @Muhammad, his application might be written in c++, then you don't need to distribute any frameworks. You usually need vcredist though and that is a couple of MB.

Comment: @Albin i created vc++ winforms project in vs 2010 and it uses .NET namespaces. Moreover i don't c clickonce functionality for this project. how can i deploy it if i decided to go for it. i need one click kind of installer where end user does not have to move files around his file system because they want installation to be unsupervised without any internet access

Comment: @Muhammad: you misunderstood Albin, he was talking about a native C++ application, not a C++/CLI application. @Albin: using native C++ under Windows for a desktop application usually means using a C++ GUI framework like MFC or Qt, which can be statically linked to your application. But don't expect that such applications easily keep below 1MB.

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight 4 runtime is ~6MB, that is closer to 1MB than your 50MB, but not quite there.

Comment: great to hear that. can i make what i put in my question using sliverlight. i have never used it. if u can refer some start up tutorial, i will be thankful